# fill sequence of scaled numbers in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to complete a data.frame with scaled scores.
First I have a set of scores that relate to a grade, and a universal score that has been calculated.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(grade = c("X", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A", "Max"),
             score = c(0,17,25,33,41,48,60),
             universal = c(0,22,44,65,87,108,108))
```

I expand the frame to include all integer values of score

```
df %>% complete(score = full_seq(score, period = 1)) %>% 
  fill(grade, .direction = "down")
```

I now want to complete the universal score that relates to each integer score based on the relative steps between the previously defined universal scores for each grade.

This is based on a conversion/scaling factor:
(universal boundary for grade above - universal boundary below)/(score boundary grade above - score boundary grade below)
For the grade U this would be (22-0)/(17-0) = 1.29.  Each previous score is summed with this factor to find the corresponding next universal score.

So the first part of the result should look like this:

```
score  grade   universal
0   U   0
1   U   1.29
2   U   2.59
3   U   3.88
4   U   5.18
5   U   6.47
6   U   7.76
7   U   9.06
8   U   10.35
9   U   11.65
10  U   12.94
11  U   14.24
12  U   15.53
13  U   16.82
14  U   18.12
15  U   19.41
16  U   20.71
17  N   22.00
```

I'm trying to achieve this with Tidy principles and various combinations of group_by(), complete(), seq(), etc., but haven't been able to achieve it in a neat way.  I think my problem is that my max value is outside the grouping variable.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that both provided answers have `108` as the score for all the A grades... if that's not what you want you may want to detail what should happen for the As.

Comment: That's the correct behaviour, thanks for pointing it out Gregor.  It's a feature of the aggregation rules :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R has the `approx` function to do this linear interpolation.  You can use it in a tidyverse context like this:

```
df %>% 
  complete(score = full_seq(score, period = 1)) %>% 
  fill(grade, .direction = "down") %>% 
  mutate(universal = approx(x=score,y=universal,xout=score)$y)

# A tibble: 61 × 3
   score grade universal
   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
 1     0 X          0   
 2     1 X          1.29
 3     2 X          2.59
 4     3 X          3.88
 5     4 X          5.18
 6     5 X          6.47
 7     6 X          7.76
 8     7 X          9.06
 9     8 X         10.4 
10     9 X         11.6
```

Comment: Thanks George, much appreciated; this has solved my problem.  I ran both your solution and Gregor's and yours was a little faster
    `
                   min       lq             mean       median  uq         max       neval
 George  14.3250 15.44485 21.01164 16.1546 17.3139 389.3693   100
 Gregor   19.0568 19.64090 22.50400 20.7002 22.7699  47.6420   100
`

Comment: Nice one! I tried to get `approx` working, but didn't get it right. Nice to see the solution! (I was missing the `xout` arg)

Comment: Thanks.  I expect most of the time is taken up in expanding and filling the df?

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% mutate(
  inc = c(diff(universal) / diff(score), NA)
) %>%
  complete(score = full_seq(score, period = 1)) %>%
  fill(grade, inc, .direction = "down") %>%
  group_by(grade) %>%
  mutate(universal = first(universal) + (row_number() - 1) * inc) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  print(n = 30)
# # A tibble: 61 × 4
#    score grade universal   inc
#    <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     0 X          0     1.29
#  2     1 X          1.29  1.29
#  3     2 X          2.59  1.29
#  4     3 X          3.88  1.29
#  5     4 X          5.18  1.29
#  6     5 X          6.47  1.29
#  7     6 X          7.76  1.29
#  8     7 X          9.06  1.29
#  9     8 X         10.4   1.29
# 10     9 X         11.6   1.29
# 11    10 X         12.9   1.29
# 12    11 X         14.2   1.29
# 13    12 X         15.5   1.29
# 14    13 X         16.8   1.29
# 15    14 X         18.1   1.29
# 16    15 X         19.4   1.29
# 17    16 X         20.7   1.29
# 18    17 E         22     2.75
# 19    18 E         24.8   2.75
# 20    19 E         27.5   2.75
# 21    20 E         30.2   2.75
# 22    21 E         33     2.75
# 23    22 E         35.8   2.75
# 24    23 E         38.5   2.75
# 25    24 E         41.2   2.75
# 26    25 D         44     2.62
# 27    26 D         46.6   2.62
# 28    27 D         49.2   2.62
# 29    28 D         51.9   2.62
# 30    29 D         54.5   2.62
# # … with 31 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor! This solved my problem; much appreciated.  George's solution was a little faster

Comment: George's solution is also nicer for relying on a built-in function and less manual calculation. Definitely the better answer.